# PHP Page Ranking according to IP & location

Tags: php, mysql, location, ip, analytics

I have a website which is content based. There are more than 500 pages and it is increasing. I am also using Google Analytics but I want to discover which pages are popular on different locations. I could not find a simple solution on Google Analytics so I implemented my own system.

Everytime a user opens a page, I record 4 columns:
id_user, id_page, time, IP_user

```
for IP field I am using:
//Test if it is a shared client
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])){
  $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
//Is it a proxy address
}elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])){
  $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
}else{
  $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
//The value of $ip at this point would look something like: "192.0.34.166"
$ip = ip2long($ip);
//The $ip would now look something like: 1073732954
```

This code encodes IP to a smaller number for database efficiency. For geoLocation info I use a call to http://ipinfo.io/ with user IP,it gives me the location. I am not recording country and city since I believe it will slow down page speed.

Two analyze data I should get the locations, so I prepared a CRON job to insert city & country to the table I mentioned from IP. But http://ipinfo.io/ limits 120 lookups per minute. [2] So this limitation can make trouble in the future.

I would like to ask you if the system I designed has flaws? Or does anybody know a better system to track location of the users without decreasing page speed?

Comment: Server logfiles alone (which will barely affect service speed at all) might provide you with rich enough data for subsequent analysis.

Comment: Yes, it is a way. But server logs keep much more detail which I do not want to handle like each document requests and other pages that I am not interested in.

Comment: Still, it is more efficient to scan the web server log to gather the data.  You could even copy it to another machine to offload the web server itself.  While parsing the log, you can cache, summarize, lookup, etc, much of the stuff you need to do.  That way, you are possibly storing even less stuff in the db.

Comment: You could always configure the server to log the requests in which you are interested to a separate file.